# How to display every odd word using a shell script?

Tags: shell, unix, terminal, sh

This is the code I have so far

```
#!/bin/sh

echo $0

echo $* | awk '{ print $NF % 2 == 1}'
```

I need to display the shell script file name and every odd word of each argument, I can only print every odd line so far with awk or sed. What other method could I use and how?

Comment: That code seems to print 1 if the number of words is odd and zero otherwise.  It doesn't seem to display any of the words.  Using `echo $*` would be better written as `echo "$*"` (and for once `"$*"` is fine; usually, `"$@"` is more appropriate, and it would work too here).  Then you need to keep track of whether each argument is an odd or even 'word' (and `awk` is appropriate for the task).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works:

```
echo "$*" | awk '{ for (i = 1; i <= NF; i++) if (++j % 2 == 1) print $i; }'
```

For each field in the current line, if the incremented word number (`j`) is odd, print the word (`$i`).